# Parametric Polymorphism vs Subtype polymorphism F#

Tags: inheritance, f#, functional-programming, parametric-polymorphism, subtyping

What is the difference (if any) between these two F# type signatures?

```
UseTheStream<'a when 'a :> Stream> : 'a -> unit
```

and

```
UseTheStream : (stream : Stream) -> unit
```

Do they mean the same thing in this case?

msdn says the following about the (:>) Type Constraint

```
type-parameter :> type --   The provided type must be equal to or derived from the type      specified, or, if the type is an interface, the provided type must implement the interface.
```

This would indicate that the two signatures are saying the same thing. So Functionally, how are they different?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are different. Most importantly, the first function is generic. In your example it probably doesn't matter, but if the type parameter affects the function's return type, it does:

```ml
let UseTheStream (stream: #Stream) = stream
let UseTheStreamStrict (stream: Stream) = stream

let s1 = new MemoryStream() |> UseTheStream
let s2 = new MemoryStream() |> UseTheStreamStrict
```

`s1` is `MemoryStream`. `s2` is `Stream`.

NOTE: `#T` is shorthand for `'U when 'U :> T`.