# Wildcard Type inference with abstract class

Tags: interface, f#, abstract-class, type-inference

In the process of improving my F#, I have been experimenting with type inference and [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233215.aspx)

I am often puzzled by the work required to prepare type signatures for abstract methods in [abstract classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483471.aspx) and [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233207.aspx) when (a) the type signature is a mess and (b) when I don't know exactly how the type signature will look like (I usually start from the abstract class and then derive).

This is a toy example for a (b) scenario where I don't know if derived classes might require additional parameters to accomplish their tasks. What I just know is that I'd like the class to present an event (`feedAvailable`) and have two operations (`Activate` and `Deactivate`) that return unit.

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type DataSource () = 
    let mutable isActive = false
    let feedAvailable = new Event<_> ()
    abstract member Activate: _ -> unit
    abstract member Deactivate: _ -> unit

type NotAbstract () =
    inherit DataSource ()
    override this.Activate (a: int) = 
        printfn "active: a = %i" a
    override this.Deactivate (a: float) = 
        printfn "Stopped: a = %i" a

type NotAbstractTextual () =
    inherit DataSource ()
    override this.Activate (a: string, b: int) = 
        printfn "active: a = %i" a
    override this.Deactivate (a: string, b: string) = 
        printfn "Stopped: a = %i" a
```

The following code does not compile.
Is there a trick to defer the type signature for functions within abstract classes and interfaces?

One solution could be the use of [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233215.aspx).

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type DataSource<'a, 'b> () = 
    let isActive = false
    let feedAvailable = new Event<_> ()
    abstract member Activate: 'a -> unit
    abstract member Deactivate: 'b -> unit

type NotAbstract<'a, 'b> () =
    inherit DataSource<'a, 'b> ()
    override this.Activate (a) = 
        printfn "something"
    override this.Deactivate (b) = 
        printfn "something"

type NotAbstractTextual<'a, 'b> () =
    inherit DataSource<'a, 'b> ()
    override this.Activate (a, b) = 
        printfn "something else"
    override this.Deactivate (a,b,c) = 
        printfn "something else"
```

However, that does not solve all the problems, f.ex varying on the number of parameters without creating ad-hoc `types` and cluttering the generics signatures as in:

```
type ClassUsingTheDataSource<'a, 'b, 'ds when 'ds :> DataSource<'a,'b>> (dataSource: 'ds) =
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what your trying to do is not possible.

Your trying to make two of the member functions on DataSource generic but making the subtype specific. You can't do that when the generic parameters are not part of the actual type. This is not a problem with F#, you wouldn't be able to do it in C# either, see below for what you can do in C#.

Sorry I can't give you an more in depth explanation.

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract string Activate<T>(T t);
    public abstract string Deactivate<T>(T t);
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override string Activate<T>(T t)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override string Deactivate<T>(T t)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there is no reason for the constructor argument to `ClassUsingTheDataSource` to be of the exact type `'ds`; it is sufficient to be of the abstract type `DataSource<'a, 'b>`. Therefore you can write it like this:

```
type ClassUsingTheDataSource<'a, 'b> (dataSource: DataSource<'a, 'b>) = // ...
```

You can still call this constructor without an explicit cast, if that's what you were afraid of:

```
let f() =
    ClassUsingTheDataSource(NotAbstract())

// val f : unit -> ClassUsingTheDataSource<'a, 'b>
```

Comment: I think that, on a second thought, my initial definition `type ClassUsingTheDataSource<'a, 'b, 'ds when 'ds :> DataSource<'a,'b>> (dataSource: 'ds) = ..` which (if I am not mistaken) could be compressed using `#DataSource` is *not* equivalent to `type ClassUsingTheDataSource<'a, 'b> (dataSource: DataSource<'a, 'b>) = // ...`. See for example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642253/parametric-polymorphism-vs-subtype-polymorphism-f). Did I get it right?

Comment: It is indeed not quite equivalent. My point was, are you sure you need `'ds :> DataSource<'a,'b>`? In most cases, taking a `DataSource<'a, 'b>` as argument is sufficient (and simpler).